# How to split a string array and print string and numbers

Tags: java

Given a String array with student name and their marks in subjects Maths , Science and Social  as {"Xavier Telly 20 30 40", "Leban JOHN 40 70 90"}
Write an algorithm to print  Student Name and average of marks.
For example above problem output should be {Xavier Telly 45, Leban JOHN 66}

Comment: Answering your own questions is ok, but this just isn't a good question. It doesn't appear to have been proof read, it also doesn't have any attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: `String string = "ABC XYZ 20 30 40"; String text = string.replaceAll("\\d+ ?", "").trim(); int[] numbers = java.util.stream.Stream.of(string.replaceAll("\\D", " ").trim().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); double average = 0.0d; for (Integer i : numbers) { average += i; } average = average / (double)numbers.length;  System.out.printf(text + " = %.2f", average);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can achieve above through below program.

package practise;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class stringArrayWithTexNumb {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String[] input = {"ABC xyz 40 30 20","DEF 10 11 12"};
    averageMarks(input);
    

    
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
      return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");  //match a number with optional '-' and decimal.
    }

public static void averageMarks(String[] request) {
    
    String[] result=null;
    Map<String,String> splittedArray = new HashMap<>();
    String[] abc;
    int cnt  = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    Map<String,Integer> avgValue = new HashMap<>();
    StringBuffer objAlpha;
    for( String s : request)
    {
        objAlpha= new StringBuffer();
        abc = s.split(" ");
        for(String obj: abc) {
         
            
         if(isNumeric(obj)) {
             sum = Integer.parseInt(obj) +sum;
             cnt = cnt+1;
         }else {
            objAlpha.append(obj); 
            objAlpha.append(" ");
         }
        
        
        }
        avg = sum/cnt;
        avgValue.put(objAlpha.toString(), avg);
        
    }
    System.out.println("hello"+avgValue);
    
}
```

}